# Generating Signed Bundle fails but generating regular Bundle succeeds Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have a React Native (0.59.10) project and I want to start using the new [Google App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) program for smaller builds, downloads, etc. In order to enroll in this program I need to upload the exported app signing key form Android Studio:

> Export your key from Android Studio. From the Build menu, select
>   Generate Signed Bundle/APK. Select the Bundle option and press Next.
>   Select Export the encrypted key and press Next.

However when I go through this process it fails during the build with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > java.util.ConcurrentModificationException (no error message)
```

The odd thing is if I just choose to bundle the app (without signing) it works without problem. I'm also able to build the signed APK and upload it to the play store with

`./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Here is my project gradle file:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    playServicesVersion = "11.0.2"
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1")
        classpath("com.jaredsburrows:gradle-license-plugin:0.8.41")
        classpath("embrace-io:embrace-swazzler:3.1.6")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                        details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Things I've Tried

- Updating / Reinstalling the Android Support SDK
- Updating / Reinstalling the Google Support SDK
- Removing all packages and reinstalling with Yarn
- Upgrading the Gradle versions
- Updating individual npm packages
- Clean / Rebuild / Invalidate & restart Android Studio

Any help or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've managed to create a signed release APK, I assume you have all the keystore & signing setup done.

What I did for the Google App Signing is to use the second option (Export and upload a key from a Java keystore) instead of the first one. Just download the PEPK tool and follow the instruction the Play Store Console gives (they give the command to create the file you need to upload).

For creating bundle instead of APK; from inside the android folder use command

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

The created bundle can be found in

> android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab

This is the bundle file that I upload to Google Play